# 'How can I obtain the last digit from a number in C?

Tags: c

'How can I obtain the last digit from a number in C? For example I want to obtain the "5" from number "125", or "1" from number "24581". I have tried some division operations but it's not working.

Comment: `return number % 10;`

Answer (score 0):

Using sscanf you can convert an int into a string, then you can get all the digits you want

Comment: it's overkill when one just needs the last digit